# Using a custom form for Spring Security Waffle authentication instead of the browser popup

Tags: java, spring-mvc, browser, spring-security, waffle

I am creating a Spring MVC application that authenticates using Waffle. I have successfully configured it and it works just fine, but I would like to use a custom form instead of the browser popup when the browser does not automatically send their network credentials.

I have modified my configuration to use `formLogin()` hoping that it would use my existing authentication, but no luck.

```
package com.zeroalpha.waffledemo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;

import waffle.spring.NegotiateSecurityFilter;
import waffle.spring.NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private NegotiateSecurityFilter securityFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .addFilterBefore(this.securityFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(this.authenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
                .formLogin();

    }

}
```

This would be the ideal behavior:
[image: Waffle Flow]

update: Major Progress! I have successfully got the form to authenticate using Windows network credentials. Here's how I did it:

First of all, let me show you the bean declarations I left out of my original post. They are located in a separate class.

```
// Waffle Spring Security Beans
@Bean
public WindowsAuthProviderImpl windowsAuthProvider() {
    return new WindowsAuthProviderImpl();
}
@Bean
@Autowired
public NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider negotiateSecurityFilterProvider(final WindowsAuthProviderImpl windowsAuthProvider) {
    return new NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider(windowsAuthProvider);
}
@Bean
@Autowired
public SecurityFilterProviderCollection waffleSecurityFilterProviderCollection(final NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider negotiateSecurityFilterProvider) {
    final List<SecurityFilterProvider> securityFilterProviders = new ArrayList<SecurityFilterProvider>();
    securityFilterProviders.add(negotiateSecurityFilterProvider);
    return new SecurityFilterProviderCollection(securityFilterProviders.toArray(new SecurityFilterProvider[]{}));
}
@Bean
@Autowired
public NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint(final SecurityFilterProviderCollection securityFilterProviderCollection) {
    final NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint = new NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint();
    negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint.setProvider(securityFilterProviderCollection);
    return negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint;
}
@Bean
@Autowired
public NegotiateSecurityFilter waffleNegotiateSecurityFilter(final SecurityFilterProviderCollection securityFilterProviderCollection) {
    final NegotiateSecurityFilter negotiateSecurityFilter = new NegotiateSecurityFilter();
    negotiateSecurityFilter.setProvider(securityFilterProviderCollection);
    return negotiateSecurityFilter;
}
@Bean
public WaffleAuthenticationDetailsSource waffleAuthenticationDetailsSource() {
    return new WaffleAuthenticationDetailsSource();
}
```

Now, this is how I got the generated spring security form to authenticate with Windows network credentials

First, I added this bean of type `waffle.spring.WindowsAuthenticationProvider`

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public WindowsAuthenticationProvider windowsAuthenticationProvider(final WindowsAuthProviderImpl windowsAuthProvider) {
    WindowsAuthenticationProvider provider = new WindowsAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setAuthProvider(windowsAuthProvider);
    return provider;
}
```

Then I added it to `SecurityConfig.java` and used it to set the authentication provider in the http security chain

```
...

@Autowired
public WindowsAuthenticationProvider windowsAuthenticationProvider;

@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .addFilterBefore(this.securityFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(this.authenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
            .authenticationProvider(windowsAuthenticationProvider) // Set authentication provider here
            .formLogin()
            .authenticationDetailsSource(waffleAuthenticationDetailsSource);

}
```

Now I just have to figure out how to only use the form if the browser doesn't send the credentials! Hmmmm....

Comment: When you submit an user name or password incorrect in form login, What is the result?, do you have a custom exception handler

Comment: @ronielhcuervo no custom exception handler, just the default Spring Security error form.